# Using gitmodules for plugins

Tags: git, git-submodules

**I'm looking for a solution for my following usecase:**

---

I have a CMS which stores the modules/plugins in seperate folders.

- src/Frontend/Modules
- src/Backend/Modules

---

I have a module is structured like this:

- src/Frontend/Modules/{ModuleName}
- src/Backend/Modules/{ModuleName

---

**I would love to:**
Use git submodules to add the modules foreach project I make, so I can easily update the module repository if needed fromout the project.

---

**I have the following issue**: If I add the submodule to my project on path "/" as that's the path it should be, it prompts me an error that the directory already exists (Ofcourse).

---

**My best solution I can think of**: Split the module in two, having Frontend and Backend as it's own repository foreach plugin (unwanted).

---

**What I would love is that I can just add my module as a git submodule, without the need of splitting it up in two seperate modules.**

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you rearrange the structure so it says `src/Modules/{ModuleName}/(Frontend|Backend)` ? It's up to my knowledge impossible to track 2 separate directories as a single submodule. You can always create symlinks later on to reflect the original structure if needed.

Comment: Yes that is the issue, I can't do that as that's the CMS making the rules for me. Using symlinks might work yes but not very clean imo.

Comment: One warning on submodules: you mention that you want to "easily update the module from out the project". Submobules are "symlinks" to a particular commit of another repository. So you need to update this "symlink" to point to new commits if you want the updates of the module to be visible in the CMS.

Comment: Well updating the submodule's repo is just about pushing and pulling data from the online repository ( Github ). But since I can't use submodules properly with my configuration I've to look for either another solution, or a different CMS all together...